# Term for Reflective Web

Tags: web, reflection, metadata, history, canonical-link

Years ago, possibly in the late 90s, someone proposed having websites contain information that described what they did. This may have been a precursor to meta-tags. I believe it was an effort to help machines categorize websites and offer suggestions when doing a search. So the tags would have been used to describe the site content instead of meta information regarding the page itself.

I'm looking for the term that was used. It was something like "The Intrinsic Web" or "The Reflective Web". Whatever it was, it effectively fizzled out once Google came along with their fancy search algorithm.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Maybe the term you're looking for is `Semantic Web`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "The Semantic Web" is it. Thank you SurvivalMachine!